# Google Script for Google Form Responses - Send email when a new email address is added to column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm very new to writing scripts, and I've been stuck on this same script for weeks now.

I have a Google Form with a question that asks staff to list an email address if an additional person needs to be contacted when their form is submitted.

I'd like to write a script for the Form Responses Spreadsheet that will automatically send an email to the email address added to column N, when their email is added to this sheet.

I'd like the email to also include the URL link to the spreadsheet so they can reference the response. (Or even better: could the email include the data from their form submission?!)

I'd also like to have the emails come from a specific email address (will they only come from the account that is writing the script?)

I can get the script to run, but it is not successfully sending to the email address that is ADDED to the sheet, and I can't figure out how and where to add the trigger to send the email when a new email address is added to column N. It also seems to be triggering an error due to any cells where an email is NOT listed in column N.

Can someone draft a sample script for me that meets the criteria above?

Tab name: Form Responses 1

Emails in: Column N (N2:N5000)

Send email: anytime an email address is ADDED to column N (skip any blank cells)

Email text: include values added to form response/new row?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

save the following code in the app script of the spreadsheet that contains the Form responses:

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {

 let sheetName = e.range.getSheet().getName();
 if(sheetName == "Form Responses 1"){

   let eventVals = e.namedValues;
   let emailAddress = eventVals["*Replace with email field name*"].toString();

   if(emailAddress != ""){

    let bodyText = "";
    let keys = Object.keys(eventVals);

    keys.forEach((key, index) => {
     bodyText += `${key}: ${eventVals[key]}\n`;
    }); 

    let subject = "*Replace with subject of email*";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,subject,bodyText);

   } 
  }  
}
```

Please, raplace the text in the code between ** with the required information.

After saving the code in the App script. Please, set a trigger by cliking on the "clock" on the left pane, then click on the "+ Add Trigger" button: [Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNdVd.png)

After setting the trigger, accept all permissions required by the Google.

---

New code based on comment "Is there any way to re-order or re-organize the order in which the Google Form fields are listed in the email that is generated?"

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {

 let sheetName = e.range.getSheet().getName();
 if(sheetName == "Form Responses 1"){

  let eventVals = e.values;
  let emailAddress = eventVals[13];

  if(emailAddress != ""){

   const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
   const headers = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
   let bodyText = "";
  
   for (let i = 0; i < eventVals.length; i++){
    bodyText += `${i+1}. ${headers[0][i]}: ${eventVals[i]}\n`;
   }
   
   let subject = "subject of the email";
   MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,subject,bodyText);
   
  } 
 }  
}
```

This second script access the e.values instead of e.namedValues since e.values come in order as the columns of the spreadsheet, the downside of that function is that the headers are not included so it is needed to access the headers from the spreadsheet and then place things together in the for loop.

Comment: I tried this and it's not producing the desired effect.

Should the "email field name" be the label (column header in row 1, column N) in column N where the email addresses are coming from?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  *Replace with email field name* should be replaced with the header of column N. Please make sure that there is no other question with the same title.

Comment: This is producing an error and isn't generating the desires messages, 

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')
onMyFormSubmit @ Code.gs:3

Comment: Here's an image of what I've entered: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VvbgrGS4aPQo40AFIsm1rn-jAY6amVCV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I believe the reason you getting that message is because you are trying to run the code by clicking on the "Run" button of the script. Please ensure you have set a trigger as I described on the answer and then fill the form with a real email address. That email address will receive the email with the information.

Comment: Is there any way to re-order or re-organize the order in which the Google Form fields are listed in the email that is generated? It seems to have randomized the order of the fields and they don't necessarily make sense out of order when sent along.

Comment: Hmm. It can be possible but that means changing a bit the code. I will update my answer shortly.